# Найти число с максимальной суммой цифр

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
def func(arr):     
    sum = 0
    result = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        sum = 0
        arr[i] = list(str(arr[i]))
        for j in range(len(arr[i])):
            sum += int(arr[i][j])
        result.append(sum)
        x = result.index(sum)
        print(x)
    
array = [120, 125, 365, 450]
print(func(array))
```

Что я делаю: сначала нахожу сумму цифр числа, чтобы найти максимальное. По индексу максимального числа из полученных сумм хочу найти максимальное из `array`.

До `append` все хорошо, но с индексом и нахождением числа проблема...

Comment: array = [120,125,365,450]; print(max(array)) ([max()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_max.asp) - встроенная функция пайтона)

Comment: Если бы так просто было))) Прочитайте мой комментарий.

Comment: или нужно вернуть не 450 (максимальное), а 365, у которого максимальная сумма цифр? ps по описанию как раз и не скажешь, что вы на самом деле хотите получить

Comment: Да 365 нужно вернуть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В дополнение к [ответу от entithat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1273376/420098).
Больше текста, но без зубодробительности однострочников пайтона ;)

```
# функция для определения суммы чисел
def sum_nums(num):
    result = 0                    # текущая сумма - 0
    for ch in str(num):           # для каждого элемента в числе, переведенном в строку:
        result += int(ch)         # добавить инт элемента к результату
    return result

# основная ф-ция
def max_sum_num(arr):
    max_num = arr[0]              # первый в списке - текущий максимальный
    max_sum = sum_nums(arr[0])    # то же для суммы
    for el in arr[1:]:            # для каждого элемента, начиная со второго:
        el_sum = sum_nums(el)     # вычислить сумму
        if el_sum > max_sum:      # если больше текущей:
            max_num = el          # обновить максимальное число
            max_sum = el_sum      # обновить максимальную сумму
    return max_num
```

```
array = [120,125,365,450]
max_sum_num(array)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но все же хотелось адаптация под ту часть кода, которая у меня есть, а не новый код. Иначе понимания не придёт. Но в целом спасибо!

Comment: Насколько тяжело всё-таки читается код с индексацией и т.д. по сравнению с чистой функциональщиной )

Answer (score 4):

Находим максимальный элемент массива `array` по ключу:

- Из числа `365` (к примеру) делаем список `['3', '6', '5']`.
- Находим сумму элементов  списка `sum(...)`, при этом переводя их в `map(int, ...)`.

```py
array = [120, 125, 365, 450]
print(max(array, key=lambda x: sum(map(int, str(x)))))
```

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: @Jack_oS, еще раз проверьте :)

Comment: да, все ок, это что-то с pycharm было и его django console...